# Behavior differ between running application in IntelliJ and from jar

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar, jetty

I have written an application using Jetty as a server. I wish to package my application into a `.jar`, so I may put it in a Docker container later on.

When I run my application through IntelliJ, everything seems to be working as it should, and I can reach my `index.html` from `localhost:2222`. However, when I package my application (using `mvn clean compile assembly:single`) and run my jar by typing `java -jar myapplication.jar` in the shell, my `index.html` on `localhost:2222` returns `HTTP Error 404`.

My `App.java`:

```
public class App  {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.packages("mypackage");
        ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));

        Server server = new Server(2222);


        ResourceHandler handler = new ResourceHandler();
        handler.setBaseResource(org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource
                .newClassPathResource("index.html"));

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/*");
        context.addServlet(servlet, "/*");


        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.addHandler(handler);
        handlers.addHandler(context);

        server.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } finally {
            server.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

When running the application in IntelliJ **and** as jar, I get the following output (may be of interest?):

```
2015-11-06 09:25:00.991:INFO::main: Logging initialized @279ms
2015-11-06 09:25:01.238:WARN:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@490d6c15{/,null,null} contextPath ends with /*
2015-11-06 09:25:01.238:WARN:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Empty contextPath
2015-11-06 09:25:01.250:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.3.v20140905
Nov 06, 2015 9:25:01 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.7 2014-03-12 18:11:31...
2015-11-06 09:25:02.294:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@490d6c15{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-11-06 09:25:02.306:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@268f106e{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:2222}
2015-11-06 09:25:02.306:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1688ms
```

I am not posting my file of Jersey-methods, since I don't think it is relevant for my question.

So, what is the magic of packaging this up to a jar that can recognize my `index.html` at `localhost:2222`? Is it some environment settings in IntelliJ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't mix `ResourceHandler` and `ServletContextHandler`, you are duplicating static content effort *(**3 times over** with Jersey in play)* and will get unreliable results.

Drop the `ResourceHandler`, set the required `ServletContextHandler.setBaseResource()`, and add a `DefaultServlet` to your context.

```java
    // Figure out what path to serve content from
    ClassLoader cl = App.class.getClassLoader();
    // We look for a file, as ClassLoader.getResource() is not
    // designed to look for directories (we resolve the directory later)
    URL f = cl.getResource("static-root/index.html");
    if (f == null)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find resource directory");
    }

    // Resolve file to directory
    URI webRootUri = f.toURI().resolve("./").normalize();
    System.err.println("Main Base Resource is " + webRootUri);

    // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
    // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
    server.setHandler(context);

    // Jersey setup
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages("mypackage");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config)), "/*");

    // Lastly, the default servlet for root content (always needed, to satisfy servlet spec)
    // It is important that this is last.
    ServletHolder holderDef = new ServletHolder("default",DefaultServlet.class);
    holderDef.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
    context.addServlet(holderDef,"/");
```

> Note: since you setup Jersey at the url-pattern `/*` you should know that Jersey is responsible for serving all static content, not Jetty.